# When I run this program it prints Klkb, why is that? I have broken it down and it seems that there might be a problem with the variable ciphertext

Tags: python

```
Key        = int(input('How much would you like to shift your code by?'))
message    = input('Write the message that you would like to encrypt.')



def cipherText(message):
    for letter in message:
        intValue = ord(letter)
        convInt = intValue + Key
        print(chr(convInt))
print("Here is your ciphertext:")
S2 = str(cipherText(message))

def plainText():
    for letter in S2:
        intValue = ord(letter)
        convInt = intValue - Key
        print(chr(convInt))

print('The following is your decrypted message')
plainText()
```

What is wrong with this code? It prints out klkb. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

First you do this:

```
S2 = str(cipherText(message))
```

Then:

```
for letter in S2:
```

But since `cipherText` doesn't return anything, it returns the default `None`.

And since you force that result into a string, it is `'None'` - that's what then gets mangled in your `plainText()` function.

This is a good example of why you should avoid type casting if you can. Also, you're using global variables to pass data around, where you could just pass in what you want as parameters to the function.

Finally, you don't follow Python naming conventions, which makes the code harder to read for someone familiar with regular Python. `Key` looks like a class (it should be `key`) and `cipherText` should be `cipher_text`. Some libraries deviate from this for documentation reasons across multiple platforms and languages, but when writing your own Python, you should try to follow normal naming conventions.

Your code with all those issues fixed:

```
a_key = int(input('How much would you like to shift your code by?'))
a_message = input('Write the message that you would like to encrypt.')


def cipher_text(message, key):
    result = ''
    for letter in message:
        int_value = ord(letter)
        conv_int = int_value + key
        result += chr(conv_int)
    return result


garbled_message = cipher_text(a_message, a_key)
print("Here is your cipher text: ", garbled_message)


def plain_text(garbled_message, key):
    result = ''
    for letter in garbled_message:
        int_value = ord(letter)
        conv_int = int_value - key
        result += chr(conv_int )
    return result


message2 = plain_text(garbled_message, a_key)
print('The following is your decrypted message: ', message2)
```

Of course, having two functions that do the same thing, with extra steps, is not ideal either. Here's a shorter version:

```
a_key = int(input('How much would you like to shift your code by?'))
a_message = input('Write the message that you would like to encrypt.')


def cipher_text(message, key, decrypt=False):
    if decrypt:
        key = -key
    return ''.join([chr(ord(ch) + key) for ch in message])


garbled_message = cipher_text(a_message, a_key)
print(f'Here is your cipher text: {garbled_message}')
decrypted_message = cipher_text(garbled_message, a_key, decrypt=True)
print(f'The following is your decrypted message: ', decrypted_message)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer answers your question, please accept it, so others can find it as well and no new answers need to be written.